# scala combinations with prefix

Tags: scala, combinations, prefix

What is an elegant way to generate combinations with prefixes in scala?

```
"""
   ((pre_first, pre_second), 
   (pre_first, pre_second, thing1),
   (pre_first, pre_second, thing2),
   (pre_first, pre_second, thing3),
   (pre_first, pre_second, thing1, thing2),
   (pre_first, pre_second, thing1, thing3),
   (pre_first, pre_second, thing2, thing3))
""".stripMargin
val prefixes = Seq("pre_first", "pre_second")
val things = Seq("thing1", "thing2", "thing3")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(0 to things.size).flatMap(i=>things.combinations(i)).map(prefixes ++ _)
```

Comment: It looks cleaner to me but what is the real reason this is better?

Answer (score -2):

```
    things.toSet.subsets.map(elem => prefixes ++ elem).foreach(println)
List(pre_first, pre_second)
List(pre_first, pre_second, thing1)
List(pre_first, pre_second, thing2)
List(pre_first, pre_second, thing3)
List(pre_first, pre_second, thing1, thing2)
List(pre_first, pre_second, thing1, thing3)
List(pre_first, pre_second, thing2, thing3)
List(pre_first, pre_second, thing1, thing2, thing3)
```